# "Used Credit" or "Credit Used"

Tags: grammar, word-order

Which one is correct: "Used Credit" or "Credit Used"? The context is that you have a specific amount of credit limit and you want to say how much of that credit amount has been used.

Comment: Similar: [Past participle after noun: “proposed cost” vs. “cost proposed”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63972)

Answer (score 0):

'Used' is Participle II or Passive Participle . In the phrase it is an attribute and occupies the post position after the attributed noun, because the Passive Participle  can be sometimes followed by the performer of the action. For example,  'credit used by the customer'.